# PhpMyAdmin of Xampp on Linux mint through error "Not enough privilege to view users."

Tags: mysql, linux, phpmyadmin, xampp

I just download Xampp for Linux from apachefriends.org/. And installed it on my Linux mint 18.3 machines. While installing WordPress on xampp I got error "WordPress database error: [Can't create table `ncowp`.`wp_users` (errno: 13 "Permission denied")]". And PhpMyAdmin of Xampp on Linux mint through error "Not enough privilege to view users." I try to add "root" user but same error appear. Please help.

Comment: Do you have mysql installed and configured on your system? Can you do this from your terminal 
`SELECT User, Host, Password FROM mysql.user;` ?

Comment: Hey @mercyFREAK , Thanks for your reply. Actually I could not start MySQL server from xampp control panel, so I remove all preinstalled mysql packages. But to try as per your suggestion I reinstall mariamdb packages and same previous problem appear again I could not start MySql server from xampp control panel.